# Finding and replacing two adjacent quotation marks in VIM

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

I have the following text:

```
 "Complete","2014 H2","123456","Local","789123","File of files","A","142","000","Text",""Sharp Yield Rise
    -3.7%
    Flight to Quality
    -5.6%
    Liquidity Crisis
    -11.1%
    Equity Crash
    -2.5%
    Credit Crisis
    -9.7%""^M
```

I need to replace it for:

```
"Complete","2014 H2","123456","Local","789123","File of files","A","142","000","Text","Sharp Yield Rise
    -3.7%
    Flight to Quality
    -5.6%
    Liquidity Crisis
    -11.1%
    Equity Crash
    -2.5%
    Credit Crisis
    -9.7%"^M
```

Basically I wanted to substitute the "" before ***Sharp*** and Before `^M` (EOL character).

Comment: For the example you've provided, a simple `:s/""/"/g` would do?!

Comment: but you are probably looking for something like `%s/\v""\ze(sharp|^M)/"/g`
*the ^M is typed as <C-v><enter>*

Answer (score 0):

`:%s/""/"/g`

- Simply type that in Normal mode, finally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

  - If you are in Insert mode, which is when you can type text into your file, leave it by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get back to Normal mode.
- The `%` line range specifier means to work on the whole file.
- The `/g` global modifier means to replace all matches in the specified range – by default, `:substitute` only replaces the first match in each line.